# increasing memcached limit size

Tags: memcached

I am having issues with the limit size of my memcached:

[image]

How do I increase the limit_maxbytes? as the bytes_written is more than the limit_maxbytes?

Answer (score 5):

`limit_maxbytes` is the max memory to use for items. You're using the default value - 64MB. To change this, restart the memcached and specify a value in megabytes for `-m` option, something like this:

```
memcached -d -u memcached -l <your_IP> -c 2048 -t 8 -m 1024 -p 11215
```

Comment: You can also add limit_maxbytes configuration inside /etc/memcached.conf and change the value in front of "-m 64" inside comment you will find details about the same. You will find this configuration on Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

`bytes_written` is actually the total bytes sent out from the cache in response to hits - not the total of memory used.  Total memory used is closer to `bytes` - which, in this case, is actually less than the 64mb originally allocated.
(not disputing the need to allocate more memory - just clarifying OPs misunderstanding of bytes_written.